Python transformers can't load
I have this code:
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS
from transformers import pipeline

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
model = pipeline("text-generation", model="MBZUAI-Paris/Atlas-Chat-9B")

@app.route('/generate', methods=['POST'])
def generate():
    data = request.json
    user_input = data.get("input", "")
    response = model(user_input, max_length=1000)
    return jsonify({"output": response[0]['generated_text']})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5000)

But program stops without output.
I have latest Transformers, Accelerate, SafeTensors and PyTorch. And I have Python 3.10.0.
My computer is Lenovo Yoga C-930 13IKB.
I tried this along with many other models, but only the smaller ones seem to work, like the Instruct models. Whenever I try a slightly larger model, it stops without producing any output.

It seems like your laptop does not have a dedicated GPU and has a RAM of 16 GB based on the specs for the model name. I might be wrong here, but I am going to assume this configuration and write the answer.
The model you are trying to use is ~19 GB which does not fit on your RAM. Using quantized models might help in this case but since there is no GPU that supports CUDA on your laptop, bitsandbytes quantization is not supported (CPU and other backends are currently in experimental stage).
In case you have one use you can use this code:
# pip install bitsandbytes accelerate
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM, BitsAndBytesConfig

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

model_id = "MBZUAI-Paris/Atlas-Chat-9B"
quantization_config = BitsAndBytesConfig(load_in_4bit=True)

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_id)
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
    model_id,
    quantization_config=quantization_config,
    low_cpu_mem_usage=True, 
)


@app.route('/generate', methods=['POST'])
def generate():
    data = request.json
    user_input = data.get("input", "")
    messages = [
        {"role": "user", "content": user_input},
    ]
    input_ids = tokenizer.apply_chat_template(messages, return_tensors="pt", return_dict=True, add_generation_prompt=True)
    outputs = model.generate(**input_ids, max_new_tokens=1000, temperature=0.0)
    response = tokenizer.decode(outputs[0]).split("<start_of_turn>model")[-1]
    return jsonify({"output": response})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5000)


But if you don't there is still a way you can run this on your laptop's CPU using llama.cpp.
First, install the llama.cpp Python bindings with:
pip install llama-cpp-python

Then download the quantized model by typing this in your terminal:
!huggingface-cli download mradermacher/Atlas-Chat-9B-GGUF Atlas-Chat-9B.Q4_K_M.gguf --local-dir . --local-dir-use-symlinks False

Note: Change the --local-dir parameter as needed.
Then use this code:
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS
from llama_cpp import Llama

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

model_path = "./Atlas-Chat-9B.Q4_K_M.gguf" # Download the model file first

# Set gpu_layers to the number of layers to offload to GPU. Set to 0 if no GPU acceleration is available on your system.
llm = Llama(
  model_path=model_path,
  n_ctx=4096,  # The max sequence length to use - note that longer sequence lengths require much more resources
  n_threads=2,  # The number of CPU threads to use, tailor to your system and the resulting performance
  n_gpu_layers=0  # The number of layers to offload to GPU, if you have GPU acceleration available
)


@app.route('/generate', methods=['POST'])
def generate():
    data = request.json
    user_input = data.get("input", "")

    # Simple inference example
    output = llm(f"<start_of_turn>user\n{user_input}<end_of_turn>\n<start_of_turn>model\n", # Prompt
        max_tokens=1000,  # Generate up to 1000 tokens
        stop=["<end_of_turn>"],   # Example stop token
        echo=False        # Whether to echo the prompt
    )

    return jsonify({"output": output["choices"][0]["text"]})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5000)


The input pattern is modified according to the format used in Atlas-Chat model.
I have used a 4-bit gguf quantized model here which effectively brings the model size down to 5.76 GB. This model will load on your PC comfortably while sacrificing the quality of the generations to some extent.
